# How do I access actual method argument names in Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, reflection, aop

I desperately need help on this. I've have been looking all over for a way to do this.
I am using Spring AOP in a web app running in Tomcat 7.
I am trying to use a @Before advice to print the names and values of the actual arguments of method pointcuts.
First I thought simply compiling the class files with the -g option will do the trick. That didn't work.
Then I read in a post somewhere that using AspectJ load-time weaving will for sure do the trick. So I did the following for Tomcat 7:

In my context.xml

```
<Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"/>
```

In my config.xml

```
<context:load-time-weaver weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver"/>
```

But still when I call MethodSignature.getParameterNames() it returns null.

So my question is:
Is there a way to get the parameter names of a method from within an advice? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling with debug information is a requirement.

Then you can use an instance of `org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer` to resolve the parameter names.

Comment: Bozho, Thanks for your response. Just like you I thought the LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer would do the trick but it did not. Any other suggestions?

Comment: do you have the debug information present? Because I have used it and it works

Comment: I took another look at my set-up. I suspected that proxy classes and/or interfaces where probably getting in the way. My assumptions turned to be correct. @Bozho: using LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer indeed solves the problem.